# Add GET Parameters to Play Framework 2.2 Response

Tags: java, javascript, playframework, playframework-2.2

I have a Play Framework version 2.2.2 application. It's fairly simple. I am extending the `Security.Authenticator` to handle my request authentication.

I am passing in (via the request, either `GET` or `POST`) an authorization token generated by another app on the domain. This token is looked up in the database, and will eventually return the `userId` for the user (rather than the String `userName` like in the Play demo.

What I would like to do, is append the `userId` to the GET, so that I can extract the parameter with Javascript, as all the JS code I have currently depends on having a `userId`, and not the authentication token.

Is there any way to accomplish this, or am I trying to go about this the wrong way? I need to avoid using cookies unless it's otherwise impossible.

Thanks!

**Edit**

Here is what I am intending to do broken down step by step:

- Frontend JS makes a request to Play application via GET request from a browser (eg. http://mycompany.com/playapp/home?authToken=5hgys7Sgh2u4iblahblah)
- The request contains a `authToken` parameter, used for lookup in a user auth DB table
- Play `Security.Authenticator` intercepts request before it makes it to its intended controller (let's say the controller is `Application.java`)
  -The `Secured` class that extends `Security.Authenticator` looks for the `authToken` in my `GET`  data.
  -The value is used to do a reverse-lookup of the `userId`.
  -The `Secured` class `public String getUsername(Http.Context ctx)` is overridden to return the userId as a string (eg. `"1234"`).

Now what I would like to do, is to modify the URL to append the userId on there (eg. http://mycompany.com/playapp/home?authToken=5hgys7Sgh2u4iblahblah**&userId=1234**)

I'm not entirely sure this is possible... but suffice it to say, I need to make a request via the browser, do the authentication, and then, upon successful request, let javascript know what the `userId` is. I would like to do this without setting a cookie, but that doesn't seem to likely now, the more that I think of it...

**Update:**

So what I ended up doing was setting my `userId` from inside my Secured.java on the session like this:

```
ctx.session().put("userId", userId);
```

Then, from whatever method has been authenticated with the annotation, I retreive the `userId` from the session like this:

```
Integer userId = Integer.parseInt(ctx().session().get("uid"));
```

I then pass the `userId` to my page template, and insert it into a Javascript variable. Works like a charm, and no cookies needed.

Comment: You mixed something... response has no method ... Can you show us your approach ?

Comment: Why do you want to avoid setting a cookie?

Comment: @JasonPearson - One word: Europe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you would return userId in the HTML page that the GET returns.  userId could be in the page as Javascript or as HTML.  Or return it in a cookie and the javascript can get the cookie.

Many potential security issues though.  How will you trust the userId coming back in future requests?

Comment: Thank you, this about what I figured I'd have to deal with. I'm not especially concerned with security here because the authToken and userId are checked against the authentication table on EVERY transaction. The auth token has a fairly short TTL, so there isn't much to worry about I don't think.